# ARIMA numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: time-series, prediction, statsmodels, arima, forecast

when I run the code below in Jupyter notebook, it runs fine, although when I try to run it as a python file I get an error as: `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Array must not contain infs or NaNs`

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
import numpy as np

data = np.array([347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, \
                 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, \
                 345, 345, 344, 314])

model = ARIMA(data, order=(2, 1, 0))
model_fit = model.fit()
output = model_fit.forecast()
yhat = output[0]
yhat
```

I am using virtual env, so the imported package is the same version (v0.12.1), tried downgrading it to [0.11](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6360), although it did not help.

Note that this is just a dummy code snippet.

Comment: The difference of your data is nearly constant.  This is why the model is having a lard time finding stationary parameters: `array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  -2.,   0.,   0.,   0., 0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  -1., -30.])`. I don't think an ARIMA does a good job describing this data.

Answer (score 0):

As I said this was just a simple example, which should work.
I have deleted dependencies in my virtual env and then installed it again.

Works like a charm.